# Adding Field to Raster using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster

I have a shapefile which contains X-specific field. I want to add this X-specific field (integer) to a raster dataset. I am using ArcGIS 10. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the values of your 'X' tool correspond directly to your raster, you're best of converting the shapefile to a raster based on 'X' with [Feature to Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000002v000000) and then using [Combine](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000007r000000.htm) (from the Spatial Analyst toolbox) to combine the 'X' raster with your original dataset.